# What event is raised when the mouse is moved while a button is pressed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, mouseevent

I need an event that doesn't exist in the .NET Framework's standard events. For example, mouse move while the left mouse button is down.

I also need to change some behaviors. For example, I have some buttons and I want to change the background image of each one that cursor is on while the left mouse button is down, but when I click on one button and hold down the left mouse button, when I move the mouse the other buttons will not raise any events.

What should I do? How can I create new events? How can I change behaviors?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this WPF or Windows Forms ?

Comment: I edited this to fix your English mistakes. (I hope this doesn't offend you -- I'm just trying to help :)). The edits should be visible as soon as a moderator approves them.

Comment: @Brennan: I think you forgot the title? Otherwise, thanks for editing this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that when the MouseDown event occurs on a button, that button 'captures' the mouse and doesn't release it until the button is released, which means that the MouseMove events are not received by the other buttons.

There's some code [from here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/8e85eb78-77f2-485f-9bd3-3eaa44233a8a/) which may help:

```
 // Assuming all buttons subscribe to this event:
 private void buttons_MouseMove (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
      {
       Control control = (Control) sender;
       if (control.Capture)
       {
          control.Capture = false;
       }
       if (control.ClientRectangle.Contains (e.Location)) 
       {
           Control.BackgroundImage = ...;
       }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The MouseMove-Event has an Property called 'Button' which tells you, which button is pressed.  So all you have to do is something like this:

```
void panel1_MouseMove(Object sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs e) {

    if(e.Button = MouseButtons.Left){
        //Do what you want when mouse_move with left button pressed      
    }      
}
```

Above code isn't tested, and I haven't looked up the correct spelling etc. of the Properties, just give it a little try in IntelliSense / MSDN.

You can find even more Information in the MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

For the second question, just try finding a fitting event or overwrite the WindowProc-Event-Function there you can listen to the WindowMessages and fetch what you need - more information is given on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633573%28v=VS.85%29.aspx and on http://www.pinvoke.net

Answer (score 0):

This example (one form with 2 textboxes) moves the text in a textbox to another textbox by clicking left on one and releasing the mouse on the other textbox. If you comment out the capture part, it stops working.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim MousebuttonIsPressed As Boolean = False
Dim TextboxWhereMouseDown As TextBox
Dim TextboxWhereMouseUp As TextBox
Private Sub Form1_mouseup(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
    MousebuttonIsPressed = False
End Sub
Private Sub Textbox_MouseDown(sender As TextBox, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TextboxOne.MouseDown, TextboxTwo.MouseDown ' etc for each textbox involved
    TextboxWhereMouseDown = sender
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        MousebuttonIsPressed = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Textbox_MouseUp(sender As TextBox, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TextboxOne.MouseUp, TextboxTwo.MouseUp ' etc.
    TextboxWhereMouseUp = sender
    If Not (TextboxWhereMouseDown Is TextboxWhereMouseUp) Then
        TextboxWhereMouseUp.Text = TextboxWhereMouseDown.Text
        TextboxWhereMouseDown.Text = ""
    End If
    MousebuttonIsPressed = False
End Sub
Private Sub Textbox_MouseEnter(sender As TextBox, e As EventArgs) Handles TextboxOne.MouseEnter, TextboxTwo.MouseEnter ' etc
    If MousebuttonIsPressed Then
        TextboxWhereMouseUp = sender
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Textbox_MouseMove(sender As TextBox, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TextboxOne.MouseMove, TextboxTwo.MouseMove ' etc
    If (e.Button = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) Then
        Dim Contrl As Control = sender
        If Contrl.Capture Then
            If Not Contrl.ClientRectangle.Contains(e.Location) Then ' to allow selection of text
                Contrl.Capture = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```